# VSC does not break on correct breakpoint

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, javascript-debugger

I'm trying to implement NodeJS debugging API server on top of my own debugger. I would like to use any client that is capable of debugging Node to debug through my own debugger. I'm using Visual Studio Code as a test debugging client, and I was able to implement enough message exchange to attach, set breakpoint and notify VSC that script was halted on a breakpoint. Problem is, Visual Studio Code changes "Pause" icon to "Play" to indicate that the execution is paused, but it doesn't seem to understand which breakpoint the code stopped on. No breakpoints are highlighted. And it doesn't request frame or stacktrace from the server. Before last VSC code update, it would also display message that execution is paused at the top of the stacktrace window, after last update, that message doesn't show up, but execution is still paused.

Here's the log of message exchange between server and VSC (starting with breakpoint request):

```
Request:
 {
    "command": "setbreakpoint",
    "arguments": {
        "line": 4,
        "column": 0,
        "type": "scriptRegExp",
        "target": "^(.*[\\/\\\\])?\\/Users\\/me\\/Documents\\/github\\/test\\/test\\.js$"
    },
    "type": "request",
    "seq": 8
}
Response:
{
    "seq": 9,
    "type": "response",
    "success": true,
    "running": true,
    "request_seq": 8,
    "command": "setbreakpoint",
    "body": {
        "type": "scriptRegExp",
        "breakpoint": 1,
        "script_regexp": "^(.*[\\/\\\\])?\\/Users\\/me\\/Documents\\/github\\/test\\/test\\.js$",
        "line": 4,
        "column": 0,
        "actual_locations": [
            {
                "line": 4,
                "column": 4,
                "script_id": 42
            }
        ]
    }
}
Response:
 {
    "type": "event",
    "event": "break",
    "body": {
        "sourceLine": 4,
        "sourceColumn": 4,
        "sourceLineText": "    var product = Product.get(params.pid.stringValue);",
        "breakpoints": [
            1
        ],
        "script": {
            "id": 42,
            "name": "/Users/me/Documents/github/test/test.js",
            "lineOffset": 0,
            "columnOffset": 0,
            "lineCount": 458
        }
    }
}
Request:
{
    "command": "threads",
    "type": "request",
    "seq": 10
}
Response:
{
    "seq": 11,
    "type": "response",
    "success": true,
    "running": false,
    "request_seq": 10,
    "command": "threads",
    "body": {
        "totalThreads": 1,
        "threads": [
            {
                "current": true,
                "id": 4
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

After that, VSC doesn't send any more requests in. Am I doing something wrong? Maybe somebody can point me to the location of some unit tests that are supposed to verify VSC Node debugging?

Also, request for threads doesn't seem to be in the NodeJS Debugger API specification, although Node responds to it. Is it new, or just undocumented feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following section from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/api-debugging explains what happens when a breakpoint is hit:

"Whenever the program stops (on program entry, because a breakpoint was hit, an exception occurred, or the user requested execution to be paused), the debug adapter has to send a stopped event with the appropriate reason and thread id. Upon receipt VS Code will request the stacktrace (a list of stack frames) for the given thread. If the user then drills into the stack frame, VS Code first requests the scopes for a stack frame, and then the variables for a scope. If a variable is itself structured, VS Code requests its properties through additional variables requests. This leads to the following hierarchy:..."

Debug adapter tests are here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-node-debug/blob/master/src/tests/adapter.test.ts
They test typical VS Code scenarios. You might want to look into the 'should stop on a breakpoint' test (line 108).

To save space the "stop reason" is now shown in the header of the CALL STACK viewlet:

[image]

Comment: In the end it turned out I was doing everything correctly. It's just my debugger was sending `threadID = 2` for `threads` request. And apparently VSC was just stopping at that point. Not sure why.